# How to ignore double quotes in sql update query for changing column value( value is XML)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

How to ignore double quotes in sql update query for changing column value. 
the value should not change.

`update JOURNALARTICLE set content = "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US">
    <dynamic-element instance-id="V6SjmaK7" name="bannerImage" type="document_library" index-type="">
        <dynamic-content><![CDATA[/documents/10193/199064/Meg-login-text.jpg/09a260ba-74ca-47de-b119-aa79bf372542?t=1386184650097]]></dynamic-content>
    </dynamic-element>
</root>" where id_ = 222225;`

> i am getting the following error when this query executes

**java code:** 
    statement.executeUpdate(stringBuffer.toString());

stringBuffer is XML file value.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '1.0'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeImpl(JtdsStatement.java:809)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsStatement.java:1288)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsStatement.java:1241)
    at com.dbrefresh.ImportData.insertSQL(ImportData.java:71)
    at com.dbrefresh.ImportData.main(ImportData.java:40)
```

Means it is not escaping double quotes in value. actually the value is XML, we can not change.
cloud you please suggest me how to insert XML value with out modifying.

Comment: wrap the content with single quote

Answer (score 1):

try replacing yours with this query:

```
update JOURNALARTICLE set content = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US">
    <dynamic-element instance-id="V6SjmaK7" name="bannerImage" type="document_library" index-type="">
        <dynamic-content><![CDATA[/documents/10193/199064/Meg-login-text.jpg/09a260ba-74ca-47de-b119-aa79bf372542?t=1386184650097]]></dynamic-content>
    </dynamic-element>
</root>' where id_ = 222225;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that the xml has the problem. Try creating a procedure and inside that you write the logic for update. Call the procedure from the program and pass the values. Also make use of sp_xml_preparedocument inside procedure for parsing the xml.